# how to manage the spaces between buttons in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-gui

i'm trying to make a dial pad in android with circle buttons.Just like in IOS 7.This is the link where you can see the dial pad in IOS 7.

```
http://www.google.com.pk/search?q=ios7+dial+pad&biw=1277&bih=524&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=623sVOfCC4zraOfhgYAK&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#imgdii=_&imgrc=dYMGMoj954EdzM%253A%3B4hEenGnCMC6kYM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.tekshanghai.com%252Fwp-content%252Fuploads%252F2013%252F06%252Fdial-pad.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.tekshanghai.com%252Fpromotion-free-update-to-ios-7%252F%3B640%3B1136
```

The layout is complete but the problem i'm facing is different mobile screen size.when i run my app in other mobile the space between the buttons is extend or you can say that space is increases. I also used the android:layout_weight to adjust the button automatically with screen size but it changes the shape of the button.The circle button change his shape into oval. help me to solve this problem.
**Here is the layout**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dialpad"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#fcfbdf"
    android:gravity="left" >

    <TableLayout
      android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/textView11"  
      android:background="#fcfbdf" >

        <TableRow
           android:id="@+id/dial_input_Row"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
           android:layout_weight="1" >
 <EditText
           android:id="@+id/dial_input_edit_text" 
           android:layout_width="1dp"
           android:layout_height="55dp"
           android:layout_gravity="left"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:ems="11"
           android:paddingLeft="5dp" 
           android:paddingRight="5dp"   
           android:textStyle="normal" 
           android:textSize="25dp"                    
           android:inputType="text" 
           android:background="@drawable/subtitle1" 
           android:textColor="#556854">
</TableRow>
 </TableLayout>

<LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1" 
            android:layout_width="71dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/selectorcircle"
            android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
             />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="71dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"

            android:background="@drawable/selectorcircle"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="4\nGHI" 
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="71dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"

                android:background="@drawable/selectorcircle"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="7\nPQRS" 
                android:textSize="13dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_width="71dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@drawable/selectorcircle"
            android:text="*" 
            android:textSize="18dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"  android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"  android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2" 
            android:layout_width="71dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/selectorcircle"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="2\nABC" 
            android:textSize="13dp" 

          />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="71dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/selectorcircle"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="5\nJKL" 
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="71dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/selectorcircle"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="8\nTUV" 
            android:textSize="13dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            android:layout_width="71dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/selectorcircle"
            android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector"
            android:text="0" 
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </LinearLayout> 
    </LinearLayout>   
   </RelativeLayout>
```

**selectorCircle XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:shape="oval">

  <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#eee460" />

  <gradient

        android:startColor="#bcbcbc"
        android:endColor="#afafaf"
        android:angle="360"
     />

</shape>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

You can use button instead of imageview.

Answer (score 0):

Use a GridLayoutManager ( https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html ) and set it to span into 3 columns

You will need to use a RecyclerView for this.

You can also use a GridView ( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html ) and adjust the stretch mode.

Also, the reason the button changes size is because using the layout_weight, to expand you layout sizes and since the shape is oval, it will call an oval shape to be created. For this, you can create a custom View and override the onMeasure to set both height and width of the view to be equal.

Comment: give me some other solution without changing layout